# calling a custom function from uib-pager control

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to angular / bootstrap , I want to call a custom funtion from pager control **uib-pager** , but there is no **ng-change="pageChanged()"** directive as we have it for pagination control.

I know that I can write my custom code inside **ng-model="$.vm.currentPage"**, and it works as well , but for some reason I don't want to do that.

Any hints ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have following pager code firing the change event. Just make sure you have specified the ng-model which it seems you gave done.

I have also created a sample working plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/XQmLiCZ3YA53Nas6U73J?p=preview

```
 <uib-pager total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="ListPageChanged()"></uib-pager>
```